# Why does slice [:-0] return empty list in Python

Tags: python, list, slice, negative-number

Stumbled upon something slightly perplexing today while writing some unittests:

```
blah = ['a', 'b', 'c']
blah[:-3] # []
blah[:-2] # ['a']
blah[:-1] # ['a', 'b']
blah[:-0] # []
```

Can't for the life of me figure out why `blah[:-0] # []` should be the case, the pattern definitely seems to suggest that it should be `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Can anybody help to shed some light on why that is the case? Haven't been able to find mention in the docs as to why that is the case.

Comment: The - simply means count backwards to find the starting point.   Just as `[:-2]` gives a list containing the final 2 elements, `[:-0]` gives a list containing the final 0 elements.

Comment: `[:-2]` gives a `list` containing all elements _except_ the last two.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`-0` is `0`, and a slice that goes from the beginning of a `list` inclusive to index `0` non-inclusive is an empty `list`.

Comment: Briefly discussing '-0' is '0', you have to remember that the compiler is evaluating terms as it parses, and so when it sees '-0', it ends up keeping '0'.

Comment: That's the entire thrust of "`-0` is `0`". No need to remember the same thing twice.

Answer (score 9):

Python doesn't treat `-0` any different from `0`.

```
blah[:0]
```

means all elements up to but not including the first one. This is an empty list, and `blah[:-0]` is exactly the same thing.

You can test this by checking that

```
blah[0:]
```

is the whole list, starting from the first element.