# How to return nothing for Python list slicing

Tags: python, list

I wish to have variables to control how many elements at the beginning and end of a list to skip e.g.

```
skip_begin = 1
skip_end = 2
my_list = [9,8,7,6,5]
print(my_list[skip_begin:-skip_end])
```

returns [8, 7].

As [Why does slice [:-0] return empty list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879473/why-does-slice-0-return-empty-list-in-python) shows, having skip_end = 0 gives an empty list.

In this case, I actually want just my_list[skip_begin:].

```
my_list[skip_begin:-skip_end if skip_end != 0 else '']
```

doesn't work. How can I return an empty value in the ternary operation?

I'd rather use the ternary operation inside the "[ ]" rather than do

```
my_list[skip_begin:-skip_end] if skip_end != 0 else my_list[skip_begin:]
```

or an if-else block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
my_list[skip_begin:-skip_end if skip_end != 0 else None]
```

The problem with your first solution is that the index slicing expects a number (or null value), not a string.

Alternatively:

```
my_list[skip_begin:-skip_end or None]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
my_list[skip_begin:-skip_end if skip_end else None]
```

Your line:

```
my_list[skip_begin:-skip_end if skip_end != 0 else '']
```

could have make you on the right track because it yield:

> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or **None** or have an __index__
>   method

I've got inspired by the previous answer but `if skip_end != 0` is the same as `skip_end`

Answer (score -1):

```
 my_list[skip_begin:-skip_end if skip_end != 0 else skip_begin:]
```

Comment: Not bad, but I'd rather not repeat skip_begin:.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].